# Intellij failed to detect file type

Tags: intellij-idea

I have intellij 13.1.3 Ultimate and have been using it for my PHP projects. All my files.php are nicely hightlighted for php.

This morning I had to create a new file called "report.php". At first I create it with right click > new > file, but this gave me no hightlighting. So I deleted it and tried again with a right click > new > php file with same result. Now what ever the way I create it, it thinks the file is txt (it seems so) and there is no code highlighting. It's pretty frustrating.

I have tested the creation of a new file with a different name "reports.php" but this time with right click> new > PHP file, and it came nicely highlighted. i tried to rename the file to "report.php" but it came back to no highlighting!!

It seems Intellij is stuck with the name report.php being a type text.

I tried to delete the file, restart the IDEA, recreate it the right way, no luck.
I tried power save mode on, and off. No luck.
I tried File > invalidate cache/restart, ... no luck.

I'm out of options here...

Is there a way to FORCE intellij to interpret a file? Is the name "report" a reserved word?!?!?

How can it be so stupid...

edit: I also tried the suggestion in : [IntelliJ: how to force editor to treat a file as javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790402/intellij-how-to-force-editor-to-treat-a-file-as-javascript) but php is not in the list of the Template data language

Also in settings > file types, I saw two Php file entries. One with no extention, and one properly configured. I deleted the bad one but it reappears after a restart of the IDEA!

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ: how to force editor to treat a file as javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790402/intellij-how-to-force-editor-to-treat-a-file-as-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate I tried this solution. It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using the community edition or ultimate?

Comment: I am using the Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to Settings | Editor | File Types and remove the association of "report.php" with the text file type. (The erroneous association was created because of a bug in IntelliJ IDEA, but unfortunately we don't currently have specific steps to reproduce for it.)

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem, thank you so much. And indeed now if I reproduce my steps, the file is no longer taken for a txt file...