# How to show new JavaScript file option in Intellij?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I following along a [Node.JS Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-j7uqU7sI&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_)

The instructor is using the IntelliJ IDEA to create a demo server side application with Node.JS.

The first step in the tutorial is to create a static Web Project. With the help of [Static Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363758/how-to-create-a-static-web-project-in-intellij-idea-13) , I was able to accomplish the task by installing a plugin for that feature.

The next step in the tutorial is to create a new JavaScript file in that project. The instructor was able to do this by right clicking the project name -> new -> JavaScript File (show below)[image]

However when I tried to do the same, here are the options I received [image] (selected option is new)

Does anyone know what plugins I have install to get the JavaScript File option? I tried doing a Google Search but didn't find anything. I also took a look at [Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790402/intellij-how-to-force-editor-to-treat-a-file-as-javascript) but I am not trying to tell Intellij to treat another file type as a JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript support is only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. It looks like you're running IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, which does not include JavaScript support.

Comment: Ahh I see thanks! You know what's strange though? I gave the file an extension of .js, and Intellij was able to recognize it as a JavaScript file.

Comment: It does recognize it as a JavaScript file and provides some basic syntax highlighting, and that's all. IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate provides much, much more.